# Qubes OS: No networking?

Tags: qubes-os

I am using a Lenovo T420 machine having Cubes OS 3.2 freshly installed. On the upper right corner where the system tray icons reside appears no entry that allows me to connect to my home wifi. I tried to reboot the system several times without change. Right before the install I had an up-to-date Ubuntu installation and networking was no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere on the web I read about weird interference about networking in cubes having wifi enabled or ethernet plugged in during the install. Furthermore I read about Cubes OS having trouble sometimes with Lenovo systems that have to hardware wifi toggle.

As my Lenovo Thinkpad T420 has such hardware toggle this inspired me to do the following:

1. Having Cubes OS booted without any networking icon in the system tray
2. Toggle the hardware switch to disable the wifi
3. Reboot the whole system

Directly after the restart my networking has been recognized by Cubes OS showing up the icon in the system tray. After toggling the hardware wifi switch again to enable it, available wifi networks have been listed and I were able to connect. Since then my networking works fine. Indeed I have not tested out yet if a cable connection would still work out. But it doesn't matter for me for now.